# How to assign a local IP address to a public IP/Port address using NGINX with UWSGI?

Tags: django, nginx, uwsgi

I have a web application that is running in a local server using a local IP address and the port 80. However, I would like to be able to access the web application from the Internet. Thus, I have got a public a IP address from a telecommunication company. I have configured the NGINX server as followed:

```
upstream django {
        server unix:///my_path/my_project.sock; 
        # server 127.0.0.1:8000;
    }
    
    # configuration of the server
    server {
        # the port your site will be served on
        listen      80;
        # the domain name it will serve for
        server_name local_ip_address;
        charset     utf-8;
    
        # max upload size
        client_max_body_size 75M;
    
        # Django media
        location /media  {
            alias /my_path/media;  
        }
    
        location /static {
            alias /my_path/static;
        }
        location / {
            uwsgi_pass  django;
            include     /my_path/uwsgi_params; 
        }
    }
```

In my `setting.py`file, I have used the local IP address in the `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['local IP address']`. But in my firewall, I have forwarded this IP to the public one.
I have done all the nginx configurations. When I run the application from the local IP address, it is working perfectly, but I run the application from the public IP, it is showing page not found.
How can I assign the local IP address to the public one?
Please, assist.

Comment: Your question is off-topic in StackOverflow. You have a better chance to get it answered if you move it to [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) or to [Superuser](https://superuser.com).